# How use SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW with ionic v6 Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic-native

I have implemented the permission for use SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW (pop-up window) with permission accepted but I don’t know how use or how show the pop-up window for Android.

I want show pop-up or open the application when is in **mode background**.

[image]

I try with notification push with the property  `force-start: 1` but not results success, also I try with background mode but I don’t know how show popup

Any help Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the cordova background mode  (if you are using Cordova) for that purpose.

https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode

When a notification arrives, you just move to foreground your application (all the documentation is on github).

It should work with the permission you've already granted.

Take into account that you better move your app to the back when the task you are performing finishes